# Fishing Drop Rates

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have always had a problem getting saddles in Minecraft. I know there are a few ways to do this, but I don’t really have access to any but the simplest: fishing.

So here’s my question: What are the fishing drop rates? Do they vary based on location? I’ve fished for about three Minecraft days now, and have yet to get anything other than bottles of water, fish, and an extremely low durability fishing rod.

Am I extremely unlucky or is this normal? (I play on Bedrock v.1.16.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of items you can fish up and their chances can be found on the [official wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing).

You can increase your chances of getting good items with the [Luck of the Sea](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Luck_of_the_Sea) enchantment.

For your case with saddles, you have a base chance of 0.8% to get one from fishing. With Luck of the Sea III, the chance increases to 1.9%.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really find the rates of getting some good item to be fished, but what you can do to improve your chance at getting better items is via [enchantments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing_Rod#Enchantments).

You can use [Luck of the Sea](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Luck_of_the_Sea) to get better chances of earning better items, and you can also use [Lure](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lure) to decrease the fishing time. [Unbreaking](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Unbreaking) and [Mending](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mending) are optional, but highly suggested.